# Kafka connector and Schema Registry - Error Retrieving Avro Schema - Subject not found

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I have a topic that will eventually have lots of different schemas on it. For now it just has the one.
I've created a connect job via REST like this:

```
{
 "name":"com.mycompany.sinks.GcsSinkConnector-auth2",
 "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mycompany.sinks.GcsSinkConnector",
    "topics": "auth.events",
    "flush.size": 3,
    "my.setting":"bar",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "key.deserializer":"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDerserializer",
    "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://schema-registry-service:8081",
    "value.subject.name.strategy":"io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy",
    "group.id":"account-archiver"

 }
}
```

I then push a message to that topic with a string key and an avro serialized payload. If I inspect the topic in the control center I see the correctly deserialized data coming through.
Looking at the ouput from the connect instance though I see this in the logs

```
RROR WorkerSinkTask{id=com.mycompany.sinks.GcsSinkConnector-auth2-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:487)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:464)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:320)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic auth.events to Avro:
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:487)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id 7
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject not found.; error code: 40401
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:226)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:252)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:319)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:307)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getVersionFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:158)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getVersion(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:271)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.schemaVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:184)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:153)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:215)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(AvroConverter.java:145)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:487)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:487)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:464)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:320)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

You can see from here that there are two related issues:

- `Error retrieving Avro schema for id 7`
- `Subject not found.; error code: 40401`

What bugs me is that I've specified the strategy to be RecordNameStrategy which I think should use the magic byte to go and get the schema as opposed to the topic name, but it errors on Subject not found. I'm not sure if it's actually looking for a subject name or getting a schema by the ID.
Either way by ssh-ing to the connect instance and doing a curl to 
`http://schema-registry-service:8081/schemas/ids/7` I do get the schema returned.
There is some additional logging above this stack trace which disappointingly looks like it's still using the wrong name strategy:

```
INFO AvroConverterConfig values:
    schema.registry.url = [http://schema-registry-service:8081]
    basic.auth.user.info = [hidden]
    auto.register.schemas = false
    max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
    basic.auth.credentials.source = URL
    schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info = [hidden]
    value.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
    key.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
```

Does anyone have any clues about how to resolve this? I'm using the following images:

- confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.2.0
- confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the trace, `lookUpSubjectVersion` means it tried to do a lookup under `/subjects/:name/versions` for each ID listed there, then could not find `schemaId=7` (Note: **not** version=7), though not too clear from the logs what `:name` it is trying to use here, but if that isn't found, then you'll get your `Subject not found` error. If [my PR was acccepted, the subject name would be more clear](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/821)

I believe this might be due to using `RecordNameStrategy`. [Looking at the PR for that property](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/680), I gathered it was really only tested against the producer/consumer code, and not throughly within the Connect API. As compared to the default behaviour of `TopicNameStrategy`

Which, you can see it tried to use

```
value.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
key.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
```

But looking more closely, I think you might have configured it wrong.

Simliar to how you have `value.converter.schema.registry.url`, you would actually need to set `value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy` instead.

Comment: sob, so the best thing to do is probably just have a byte[] converter and manually do the schema lookup then?

Comment: Could you try first change the property to `value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy`? Basically, the `value.converter` prefix is parsed for all configs specfic to the Value of the record, then the config name itself is `value.subject.name.strategy` would need passed into that... Similarly, if the Key is avro, set `key.converter.key.subject.name.strategy`

Comment: btw, `key.deserializer` doesn't do anything in the properties

Comment: no dice. using
```"key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://schema-registry-service:8081",
  "value.converter.value.schema.registry.url":"http://schema-registry-service:8081",
  "value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy":"io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy",``` 
gives me the same error. I'll roll my own :(
Thanks

Comment: Well, in the logs, it shows `AvroConverterConfig values`, I think there is some way to get `value.subject.name.strategy` to show the value you've set. Since `schema.registry.url` is set there (based on `value.converter.schema.registry.url`), then `value.subject.name.strategy` should work as well after the converter prefix... Note: `value.converter.value.schema.registry.url` is not a valid config since `value.schema.registry.url` is itself not a property

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this problem check that **namespace** in the variable

```java
public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$
```

it is the same as the **package** of generated java file

Comment: How does this fix an HTTP error?