# Kafka Connect ignoring the Subject Strategies specified

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I want to publish multiple table data on to same Kafka topic using the below connector config, but I am seeing below exception

**Exception**

Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema; error code: 409

The connector seems to ignore the subject strategy properties set and keeps using the old ${topic}-key and ${topic}-value subjects.

```
[2019-04-25 22:43:45,590] INFO AvroConverterConfig values: 
    schema.registry.url = [http://schema-registry:8081]
    basic.auth.user.info = [hidden]
    auto.register.schemas = true
    max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
    basic.auth.credentials.source = URL
    schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info = [hidden]
    value.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
    key.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
```

**Connector configuration**

```
    curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{
      "name": "two-in-one-connector",
      "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "xxxxxxx",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "xxxxxxx",
        "database.password": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "database.server.id": "18405457",
        "database.server.name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "table.whitelist": "customers,phone_book",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "broker:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.customer",
        "transforms": "dropPrefix",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"(.*)",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"customer",
        "key.converter.key.subject.name.strategy": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy",
        "value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy"
      }
    }'
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801680/kafka-connector-and-schema-registry-error-retrieving-avro-schema-subject-not

Answer (score 0):

Try setting strategy classes to below parameters in you connector configuration (JSON) file instead of "**key.converter.key.subject.name.strategy**" and "**value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy**"

`"key.subject.name.strategy" 
"value.subject.name.strategy"`

Comment: Have you tested these? `AvroConverterConfig` takes the prefixes of `key.converter` and `value.converter` first... Much like `value.converter.schema.registry.url`, it should be `value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy`

Comment: @cricket_007 I am already using "value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy" in my connector config. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @Suraj As I answered in the other post I linked to, I don't think these properties were tested within the Connect API, and they're not explicitly documented anywhere outside the PR that added them