# Kafka Topic and Schema Registry Subject

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a question about set up a stream processor with Kafka and different names of the topic (Kafka broker) and the subject (Schema Registry).

```
spring:
  cloud:
    schema-registry-client:
      endpoint: http://localhost:8081
      cached: true
    stream:
      function:
        definition: process
      default:
        consumer:
          use-native-decoding: true
        producer:
          use-native-encoding: true
          header-mode: none
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          group: spring-boot-kafka
          destination: abc.bla
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 3
        process-out-0:
          destination: def.bla
      kafka:
        binder:
          auto-add-partitions: false
          auto-create-topics: false
          consumer-properties:
            key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            specific.avro.reader: true
            schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
           allow.auto.create.topics: false
           auto.register.schemas: false
          producer-properties:
            key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
            schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
            auto.register.schemas: false
          brokers:
            - localhost:9092
          configuration:
            allow.auto.create.topics: false
            auto.register.schemas: false
            application.id: "${spring.application.name}"
```

First anything seems to be work fine with the Kafka broker and the schema registry but if the processor receives the event the schema registry magic starts.

Instead of sending abc as topic to the schema registry abc.bla will be send. The schema registry answers with not found.

Expected: localhost:8081/subjects/abc/versions
Unepected and wrong: localhost:8081/subjects/abc.bla/versions

```
error_code  40401
message "Subject not found."
```

I wonder what's wrong because a single producer or consumer client seems to be able to recognizing the correct subject name from the topic without explicit configuration.

Here the processor code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<ABC, DEF> process() {
        return Transformer::transform;
    }
}
```

Here the stack trace where I believe could be the problem:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema: { a long schema }
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject not found.; error code: 40401
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:298) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:368) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:453) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:440) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:254) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:444) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient.getId(SchemaRegistryClient.java:192) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:73) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
```

Does anybody an idea how I can configure `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer` or `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer` correct?

Thanks a lot,
Markus

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, now I can anser my own question.

Reason was company internal TopicNameStrategy.

```
subject:
  name:
    strategy: CompanyInternalStrategy
```

After this the topic/subject issue was fixed. An hint I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801680/kafka-connector-and-schema-registry-error-retrieving-avro-schema-subject-not)

Comment: It is more correct to use `[subject.name.strategy]: CompanyInternalStrategy` under properties